# Is there a way to listen for changes in p-columnFilter match options and call a function in Angular and PrimeNG?

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-table

Is it possible to bind a function that gets called every time user chooses between `matchOption` of `p-columnFilter`.

```
<p-columnFilter type="date">
...
</p-columnFilter>
```

[image]

example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/owuvzd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Ftable-filter-menu-demo.html

Comment: before applying the filter or after ?

Comment: before applying the filter @RachidO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a workaround to this, by creating my own `matchModeOptions` and their filter functions.

To do this I made use of `FilterService`

```
public dateIsFilter: string = "is-date";

public matchModeOptions: any[] = [
  { label: "Date is", value: this.dateIsFilter }
]

constructor(private filterService: FilterService){
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.filterService.register(this.dateIsFilter, (value: any, filter: any) => {
  // code here
  return this.filterService.filters.dateIs(value, filter)
});
}
```

Then I changed `p-columnFilter` to use custom `matchModeOptions`.

```
<p-columnFilter type="date" [matchModeOptions]="this.matchModeOptions">
...
</p-columnFilter>
```

Answer (score 2):

I searched a bit through the docs but i didn't see an official way of doing this so I came up with this solution that feels like a hack (if you find another way disregard this)

```
  @ViewChildren(ColumnFilter) columnFilters: QueryList<ColumnFilter>;
        
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.columnFilters.forEach((columnFilter) => {
      const originalFunc = columnFilter.onMenuMatchModeChange;
      columnFilter.onMenuMatchModeChange = function (
        value: any,
        filterMeta: FilterMetadata
      ) {
        originalFunc.call(this, value, filterMeta);
        // ... your code goes here
        console.log(value, filterMeta);
      };
    });
  }
```